# Powershell add-content not working

Tags: file, powershell, sharepoint

I'm trying to append to a newly created file in Powershell.

I've made the file like:

```
Set-Content ($directoryUrl+"\errors.txt") ""
```

but whenever I write to the file, it doesn't seem to append anything to it.

```
function errorLogger($fileName, $errorMessage)
{
    Write-Host ("error logger: "+$fileName+" "+$errorMessage);
    Write-Host ("errorfilelocation "+$errorFileLocation);
    Add-Content ($errorFileLocation) ($errorMessage+"`n");
}
```

The file looks empty, why is this?

EDIT:

I'm calling the function like `errorLogger($fileName, ("DIDNT CONTAIN FIELD: "+$nodeName));`

`$directoryUrl` is c:\Users\Desktop\Daniel`.

There is a file called error.txt made but nothing is in it.

Comment: is `$directoryUrl` a sharepoint url?

Comment: Nope it's a URL to a folder on my local drive. I'm able to create the file in that folder called errors.txt fine. It's just the appending that isn't working

Comment: You're gonna need to give us more details on `$directoryUrl` and possibly `$errorMessage`; I just tried this and could not repro.

Comment: Your function isn't using `$fileName` for anything except debug output; why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the `errorLogger` function like this:

```
errorLogger $fileName ("DIDNT CONTAIN FIELD: "+$nodeName);
```

The syntax for PowerShell function calls is different to that of other languages you may be familiar with.

The way you were calling it, you were passing a 2-element array, rather than two parameters.

By the way, you can simplify it further and make it more readable:

```
errorLogger $fileName "DIDNT CONTAIN FIELD: $nodeName"
```